# What is the name of the music track that plays when you are low on health in Borderlands?

Tags: borderlands, game-music-identification

In Borderlands, when you are low on health and there are lots of enemies, a dramatic Indian-sounding theme music comes on, with male vocals, drums and possibly a sitar.

Here is a video with the music, which starts at 1:49:

Does anyone know the name of that track? I can't find it online.

Comment: Most complete listing I can find: http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Soundtrack. If it's actually a full song, and not just a short sound effect, then there's a good chance it's on that list. I'd be surprised if it wasn't just a short effect, though.

Comment: Might take a look at this as well: http://kotaku.com/5945021/my-favorite-music-from-borderlands-2-isnt-on-the-official-soundtrack

Comment: I didn't realize it was just for when you are fighting Skags.  :/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just found it.

The song is ["Fighting off the Skags" by Raison Varner](https://soundcloud.com/rvarner/borderlands-fighting-off-the-skags).

I found it here on [Google's listing for Borderlands: Original Soundtrack](https://www.google.com/search?q=borderlands%20soundtrack&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en-us&client=safari#num=100&safe=off&hl=en-us&q=borderlands:%20original%20soundtrack&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAAONgVuLSz9U3SKu0TDKzAACtEsOfDgAAAA)

I asked Raison what type of music this was based on and he replied the vocals were [Tuvan Throat Singing](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuvan_throat_singing):

[image]